# How I do ORDER BY xxxx DESC NULLS FIRST (or LAST) in query builder of CakePHP 3.9 (with Postgres)

Tags: php, postgresql, cakephp, query-builder

i wrote..

```php
$query->order([
    'updated_at' => 'DESC NULL LAST',
]);
```

then...

```
2021-04-07 16:34:58 Notice: Deprecated (16384): Passing extra sort expressions by associative array is deprecated. Use QueryExpression or numeric array instead. - /var/www/shokunin3/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Expression/QueryExpression.php, line: 173
 You can disable deprecation warnings by setting `Error.errorLevel` to `E_ALL & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED` in your config/app.php. in [/var/www/shokunin3/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Core/functions.php, line 311]
Request URL: /hogehoge
Client IP: 192.168.1.1
Trace:
Cake\Error\BaseErrorHandler::handleError() - CORE/src/Error/BaseErrorHandler.php, line 168
deprecationWarning - CORE/src/Core/functions.php, line 311
Cake\Database\Expression\OrderByExpression::_addConditions() - CORE/src/Database/Expression/OrderByExpression.php, line 72
Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression::add() - CORE/src/Database/Expression/QueryExpression.php, line 173
Cake\Database\Query::_conjugate() - CORE/src/Database/Query.php, line 2260
Cake\Database\Query::order() - CORE/src/Database/Query.php, line 1191
App\Controller\FooController::bar() - APP/Controller/FooController.php, line 999
...
```

How should I write it?

What method is recommended in newest CakePHP ?

im sorry for my broken English...

Comment: The error message gives you the solution: "Use QueryExpression or numeric array instead" If you do not know how I am sure you can find that easily via a search engine.

Answer (score 2):

As the error message suggests, you can either pass an expression for the direction where you can write arbitrary SQL:

```php
$query->order([
    'updated_at' => $query->newExpr('DESC NULLS LAST'),
]);
```

```php
$query->order(function (\Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression $exp) {
    return [
        'updated_at' => $exp->add('DESC NULLS LAST'),
    ];
});
```

or you can pass a non associative array entry, ie a single string or expression (which however do not support automatic identifier quoting):

```php
$query->order([
    'updated_at DESC NULLS LAST',
]);
```

```php
$query->order(function (\Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression $exp) {
    return [
        $exp->add('updated_at DESC NULLS LAST'),
    ];
});
```

In any case make sure that you *do not* insert user data in the non-associative values or expressions, as they are being inserted into the query as-is, ie they would be prone to SQL injections!

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Raw Expressions](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/query-builder.html#raw-expressions)**
- **[API > \Cake\Database\Query::order()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.9/class-Cake.Database.Query.html#order())** (the example is going to be [fixed soon](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/15430))

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Thanks to you, our product now possible migration to CakePHP 4.x! 